# Modifying Binary Search to obtain better performances

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

[image: Problem]

Attempted Solution: (1) Given that x is an odd number. We have reduced out search set by half. The complexity is now log(n / 2) = logn - 1 in the worst case. Now we simply perform a binary search on the odd numbers.

I'm not sure if this solution is correct as I don't know the general approach to solving this type of problem. I would appreciate a solution to all 3 parts. I would certainly attempt more of the problem if I was not lost. I have tried working on this problem well in advance before posting I just simply don't know what to do.

Comment: Please let me know if you still didn't understand? I'd like to resolve if you have some fundamental problem? Often times, they are very easy and completely change the understanding of an answer. Did you understand how you'd perform binary search on new set?

Comment: @displayName Thank You so much for the explanation. I understand now that we take our original domain and create a new domain based on the given constraint and then perform binary search on that new set. In the original question is says to compute the exact worst case number of comparisons as a function of n. Is that simply log(n) - 1 for example ? I thought that was the complexity ?

Comment: Firstly, you creating a new domain is not the only way (even though that way is absolutely fine). You can also create another *layer of index* over the original set and when you perform binary search and then use some function like `GetValueAtHashedLocation(hashValue)` to get the actual values from the set in O(1) time and leave your binary search algorithm intact. You can be creative - devise thousands of ways - and have your pick. Contd...

Comment: Contd... Secondly, exact *worst number of comparison* is similar to worst case complexity only. That is what Big-O is - The worst case complexity (with the constants stripped off) or The Upper Bound. What is the worst number of comparisons you have to make in a regular binary search? Log(n). This is the worst case or Big O complexity too.

Comment: For first part, the worst case number of comparisons is k - 1. Because when we removed half of the numbers in the set (i.e. all the even numbers), we essentially reduced the depth of the binary search tree by one level (Remember that at each bifurcation in binary search, the set is reduced to half. When we reduced our search set to only odd numbers, we effectively deleted half of the original set OR, reduced the tree length by 1 level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you can find the **set** of the numbers you have to perform binary search on, you simply need to take the log of **count of numbers numbers in your new set**.* That's because after you have localized your target numbers, you only need to perform binary search on them to find *x*.

You are given total n numbers to perform the binary search on and they are the **set of {1, ..., n}.**

---

### When *x* is an odd number and *n* can be expressed as *2<sup>k</sup>*

Since x is odd, you will find it in the set's odd numbers only. So as opposed to *n*, you have *n/2* sized set to find your target number in. As *n* = *2<sup>k</sup>*, the size of your new set (let's call it *n'*), is = *n/2*. The worst case runtime for binary search on this set of numbers would be Log(numbers in *n'*) which is Log (*n*/2) or

> *(Log n) - 1 = **k - 1***

---

### When *x* is a perfect square and *n* can be expressed as *(2<sup>k</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*

In this case, your new set of target numbers is reduced to contain only the perfect square numbers. This new set would contain numbers {1, 4, 9, ..., n}. The count of numbers in this set is equal to *√n*. Think about it, when it has only 1, the count is √1 = 1. When it has 1 and 4, the count of numbers in it is √4 = 2.

Thus, with the size of your new set *n'* = *√n*, the worst case run time of binary search on this new set of numbers is again = Log(numbers in *n'*) = Log(*√n*) which is equal to

> *(Log n) / 2* = ***k***

---

### When *x* is a power of 2 and *n* can be expressed as *2<sup>(2<sup>k</sup>)</sup>*

Here, your target set to run binary search on is reduced to only those numbers which are a power of 2. Simple and straightforward, the set would contain the numbers like {1, 2, 4, 8... n}. The count of numbers in this set is equal to *(Log n) + 1*. Again, you can see that when the set has only 1, the count is (Log 1 (= 0) + 1) = 1. When set has 1 and 2, the count is (Log 2 ( = 1) + 1) = 2 and so on.

This run time complexity is again the Log (numbers in *n'*) = *Log ((Log n) + 1)*. And if you condone the 1 inside the log, it is

> *Log(Log(n))* = ***k***

Answer (score 1):

The answer is similar in all three cases. Rather than trying the integer candidates `x=i` by dichotomy, you will try the candidates that are odd (`x=2i+1`), square (`i^2`) or power (`2^i`). In all three cases, there are `k` distinct values that can be tried, and `Lg(k)` comparisons are required at worst.

The only difference is when you express these numbers in terms of `n`:

1. `Lg(k) = Lg(n/2) = Lg(n)-1`
2. `Lg(k) = Lg(√n) = Lg(n)/2`
3. `Lg(k) = Lg(Lg(n))`

Comment: How do I modify binary search in each case to achieve the complexity you listed in each case and what is the exact worst case number of comparisons asked by the modification as a function of n ?